# In ListView Which function is called while scrolling

Tags: android

```
public class SynchronisedScrollView extends ListView {

    private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;

    public SynchronisedScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SynchronisedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SynchronisedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {

        Log.d("Hello", "I am scrolled");
    //  super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
    }
}
```

I want to catch how much the listView is scrolled, so I extend ListView. I am **able** to scroll the list. But OnScrollChanged is not called. For **ScrollView** and **HorizontalScrollView**  OnScrollChanged is called whenever it scrolls. Which function is triggered when we scroll a ListView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ListView` you must explicitly register an [`onScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29) to receive `onScroll()` events.

Comment: From OnScrollListener how should I get x and y value, so that I can Scroll another ListView to that position by using ScrollTo(x,y).

Comment: Since this is `ListView` you don't get x,y. What you get in `onScroll` is index of the element. Look at javadocs of `onScroll` in the link.

Comment: thanks.. I will try. We can't play around with onScrollChanged ? :(. Then what is the use of onScrollChanged.

Comment: `onScrollChanged` javadoc says: This is called in response to an internal scroll in this view (i.e., the view scrolled its own contents). This is typically as a result of scrollBy(int, int) or scrollTo(int, int) having been called.

Comment: I have two ListView A and B. I am trying to synchronise the positions of two Lists when any on of the list is scrolled.

Comment: It's unclear to me why ListView doesn't support onScrollChanged that it inherited. If I need to work with OnScrollListener- how would I find out by which amount of x/y the view has been scrolled?

Comment: onScrollChanged has been supported long time ago (from 3.0 or 4.0,  I don't know from what exact version)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the method you are looking for is:

```
public void offsetChildrenTopAndBottom(int offset) {
    // ...
}
```

from `ViewGroup`. What you can do is extend ListView to gather the offset given to one of the `ListView`s and pass it though to the other `ListView`. Make sure that you call super.offsetChildrenTopAndBottom on the recieven end or you could easily end up with a stackoverflow.

I would create a private method and have the new Observable views.

```
public class ObservableListView extends ListView {

    private ObservableListView peer;

    // [Constructors] make sure you override all the super constructors. 
    // Can have trouble with layouts otherwise

    public void setPeer(ObservableListView peer) {
        this.peer = peer;
    }

    @Override
    public void offsetTopAndBottom(int offset) {
        super.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
        if (peer != null) {
            peer.internalVerticalOffset(offset);
        }
    }

    private void internalVerticalOffset(int offset) {
        super.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
    }

}
```

If you feel brave you can also define an xml property to give one of the `ListView`s id and let that one set up the peer relation. (I can expand if you are interested)

---

My bad, this is **non working** code. I'm trying to figure out how to do this with the hidden method. In this code I'm overriding the wrong method. Will update shortly.

---

**Update:**

Ok, after some research I think that the best option is to combine the extension of ListView with a [`TouchDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html).